# Drupal Views Entity Reference Context

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, organic-groups, entityreference

I'm running Drupal 7 with Entity Reference and Organic Groups. I have two content types, one of which is a group and the other is group content. I have an Entity Reference field (Select List) that references group content associated with the group.

I want to create a View that ONLY shows the value of the field that is selected from this Entity Reference field in the group content type.

For instance:

```
 Team: Red Sox
 Location: Fenway
```

Location is a content type (group content) and Team is the group. There are many teams and many locations but when I'm looking at the group page I want a View that ONLY shows a single location (the one SELECTED in the group content type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I realized that Views and context can't handle this on their own. I ended up using [View PHP](http://drupal.org/projects/views_php) to construct a filter that effectively filtered out all OTHER results than the one that I wanted:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
$item = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name');
$loc = $item[0]['target_id'];
$refnode = node_load($loc);
$primary = $refnode->title;
if ($primary != $row->title) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

You're welcome for this one :) If anybody has any better suggestions on how to code this feel free to comment or post alternate solutions.

Comment: After all of this work I realized that I could use Taxonomy to do the same thing without the coding....oh well...good experience though :)